# 'suexec policy violation' prevent my website from running?

Tags: cgi, internal-server-error, suexec

When I try to run my website it shows a `500 internal server error` :

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Error log says :

```
[cgi:error] [pid 13006] [client 141.101.104.167:28335] AH01215: suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details: /home/myweb/public_html/cgi-bin/index.cgi
[cgi:error] [pid 13006] [client 141.101.104.167:28335] End of script output before headers: index.cgi
```

And Suexec log says :

```
[2016-04-23]: uid: (500/myweb) gid: (500/myweb) cmd: index.cgi
[2016-04-23]: error: target uid/gid (500/500) mismatch with directory (500/500) or program (0/0) or trusted user (0/10)
```

Since the problem seems from `suexec` I decided to check at it, so in `WHM/Configure PHP and suEXEC` I found it's status On, I disabled it and try to run website again but nothing changes, I enabled it again but website still cannot running.

I went to `/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf` and removed the directive :

```
  <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
      SuexecUserGroup myweb myweb
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
```

But that didn't solve the problem and the website still shows `500 internal server error`

I changed te permission of `/home/myweb/public_html/cgi-bin/` from `777` to `755` then to `775` but the problem still exist.

Can you help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score -2):

change the permissions to `755` for all your files

and enjoy !

The problem is the un-appropriate permissions

Comment: You should tell the problems that can happen if you give 755 for ALL files. Giving 755 permission to some files can crash the system. Be carefull. If you are in a shared host enviroment it won't be a problem although.